# Convert a list of words to list of numbers that were previously assigned in Python(2.7.1)

Tags: python, list, numbers

I have a code `"aaabbbcccdddeee"` that I split up into 3 letter words (such as `'aaa'`,`'bbb'`,`'ccc'` . . . and so on) and assigned a number value to them using

```
d=dict(zip(('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'),('123','234','345','456','567')))
```

If random sequence that has

```
random='aaabbbdddccceeedddbbbaaaeeeccc'
```

How can I create a list that converts the random sequence into a list composed of the number values that were assigned previously

Example:

```
random='aaabbbdddccceeedddbbbaaaeeeccc'
```

to produce

```
'123','234','456','345','567','456','234','123','567','345'
```

Comment: Have you actually tried yet? also, is this homework?

Comment: not homework im workin with some number theory stuff and excel isnt sufficient

Answer (score 3):

```
mapping = <your dictionary>
instr = <your data>
result = [mapping[instr[i:i+3] ] for i in range(0, len(instr), 3)   ]
```

Comment: Just one small nit - `range(0, len(instr), 3)` will leave leftover slices with size < 3

Comment: it didnt work when i tried it my dictionary is in the form d=dict(zip('aaa','bbb','ccc'),('123','234','345'))) and my data is in the form instr='bbbaaaccc' i found out how to put it in the form instr="'bbb','aaa','ccc'" but the result is an error.  what i did was set mapping = dict(zip(..... and i tried instr='bbbaaaccc' and instr="'bbb','aaa','ccc'" . neither of them worked .  what should i do?

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'